# The error output was: Unknown option: '--extract-css'

Tags: angular, visual-studio

**I get the error "The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown option: '--extract-css'"**

I have a project that I have not worked in a while. It is based on a visual studio angular template. When starting the project I get the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
>   occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
>   Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown
>   option: '--extract-css'
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! angular@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --extract-css "--port"
>   "54197"` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   angular@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem
>   with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> )) System.Threading.Tasks.Task.GetResultCore(bool
>   waitCompletionNotification)
>
> InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without
>   indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error
>   output was: Unknown option: '--extract-css'
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! angular@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --extract-css "--port"
>   "54197"` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   angular@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem
>   with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware+d__3.MoveNext()

I would like to be able to run the angular template project from visual studio. It runs fine when running through angular cli.

Answer (score 2):

I found that by changing the package.json from:

> "scripts": {
>       "ng": "ng",
>       "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
>       "build": "ng build --extract-css",

to:

> "scripts": {
>       "ng": "ng",
>       "start": "ng serve",
>       "build": "ng build",

allows to run successfully the angular project template from within visual studio. Basically just removing the "--extract-css"

Answer (score 0):

To add arguments in script, add them after a `--`.

In the case above, instead of:

```
"scripts": { "ng": "ng", "start": "ng serve --extract-css", "build": "ng build --extract-css",
```

You can write it as:

```
"scripts": { "ng": "ng", "start": "ng serve", "build": "ng build -- --extract-css",
```

P.S: `--extract-css` does not work with serve, please refer to [angular issue #10532](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10532)